# Use a unique random generated short alpha numeric string as a id for model in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want users to go to a URL like the following format mydomain.com/modelname/random_string or mydomain.com/random_string...

example mydomain.com/dh7eo

I've seen [Hashids](https://github.com/peterhellberg/hashids.rb) but I wonder is this the best way to go by using standard integer IDs and the assigning the string created by Hashid to another field... Or do I replace the standard ID the ruby creates

thanks for reading!

Comment: Try `id.to_s(34)`. It should work the best in this case.

Comment: Are you aiming at just having shorter identifiers, or random identifiers so that users cannot tell how many records are in the database?

Comment: @spickermann I am hoping short identifiers (kinda like youtbue video ids).... Kind of like bit.ly as well.

I rather not use integer IDs exposed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in shorter identifers in URLs and if you do not have a problem when the real id can by calculated easily from such identifiers, than you can do something like this:

```
# in your model
UID_BASE = 36

def self.by_uid(uid)
  find(uid.to_i(UID_BASE))
end

def to_param
  id.to_s(UID_BASE)
end
```

With that in your model you can still use link builder like these:

```
redirect_to @model
redirect_to edit_model_path(@model)
link_to 'Show', @model
```

To load the model in your controller:

```
def show
  @model = Model.by_uid(params[:id]) # not params[:uid]
end
```